# TinyMce Set Max Width

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am running into an issue with TinyMce. I have a CMS that utilizes this WYSIWYG and when a user inserts a table that is larger than layouts main body, it throws the layout / template out of alignment.

So I am looking for the best solution to prevent users from inserting a table no wider than say 400px.

One thing I am trying to do is create a custom max-width param in the tinyMCE.init then in table.js check this param with the table width via form object variable.

I am able to do this part just fine. If someone creates a table in their property box they will get a pop up alerting them that they entered in a value wider than the aloud max width. That solves half the problem, What I really need though is a way to trigger a function that checks the width vs the max-width when someone tries to drag and re-size the table.

I am thinking I can trigger it off with a onmouseup event on the text field it's self or nest a function within another function to trigger it to check width. I just have no clue where this will need to be inserted. Would someone be able to give me some ideas or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for a dragend event and then check for the width.
In case the table inserted is wider you could remove it or alert a message.